# Entity Framework 4.1 - Code First: many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I want to build a relation like this ( a Zone is in the neighbourhood of x other zones )

```
public class Zone
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ZoneNeighourhood> ZoneNeighourhoods { get; set; }
}

public class ZoneNeighbourhood
{
    public virtual Zone Zone1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Zone Zone2 { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately this won't work, because the FKs generated by EF are not correct... How can i get a structure like this to work?

Example with 3 Zones: Zone 1, Zone 2, Zone 3

### Zone 1 Neighours:

Zone 2,
Zone 3

### Zone 2 Neighbours:

Zone 1

### Zone 3 Neighbours:

Zone1

Any advice?

Comment: @Dave: Sorry the relationship between Zone's and ZoneNeighbourhood's is unclear to me. I think you mean a Zone can be in another Zone, which itself maybe a child of another "Super Zone"... Is that correct?

Comment: No, i mean it like in the example i've added... It's just like an implicit neighbour relation.. like with persons: Mr. Smith is the neighbour of Mr. Jones and so Mr. Jones is implicitly the neighbour of Mr. Smith

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your mapping is not correct. You are creating self referencing entity so you need separate collection for incoming and outgoing relations. Single collection is not enough.

```
public class Zone 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("NeighbourOf")]
    public virtual ICollection<Zone> NeighbourTo { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("NeighbourTo")]
    public virtual ICollection<Zone> NeighbourOf { get; set; }
}
```

You don't need to map junction table unless you also want to add some additional properties to the relation.

If you want only single collection you must use fluent mapping:

```
public class Zone 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Zone> Neighours { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Zone> Zones { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Zone>()
                    .HasMany(z => z.Neighbours)
                    .WithMany();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, thx. But i get an "The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'NeighourTo' on type 'Zone' is not valid" when i use the class like u suggested in the 1st case

Comment: @David: That was because of type in property names. I edited it. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Dave,

How about just:

```
public class Zone {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Zone> Neighours { get; set; }
}
```

Or am I missing something? Do you NEED to model the neighbourhood as an external entity for some other reason? I wonder what database-schema the Entity-Framework would generate for that... I'm NOT an expert, in fact I'm a noob in this area. I don't THINK it has a problem with self-referncing tables like this... aleast nothing I've read so far indicates it. Let's try it and find out ;-)

Cheers. Keith.